# Compiling menu items into templates with Harp

Tags: javascript, node.js, harp

I would like to be able to generate menu items at compilation (i.e. `harp compile ./`) from a partial, based on whatever objects are in the current folder. This would be applied to markdown documents generated from another source; Harp hopefully can not only build the HTML pages but also the navigation for that section. I have been looking through the [documentation](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/) and [boilerplate projects on GitHub](https://github.com/harp-boilerplates), however I can't see any examples of this.

I have included the code I attempting to use, which is based on assumption that it could pull the objects from the "root", and would return an object somewhat similar to the [current](http://harpjs.com/docs/development/current) object.

*_header.ejs*

```
<ul>
  <% for (var page in public) { %>
    <li><a href="<%= page.path%>"><%= page.path %></a></li>
  <% } %>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
<ul>
  <% for (var i in public) { %>
  <%   var filename = public[i] %>
  <%   if (filename.indexOf(".md") > -1) { %>
  <li><a href="<%= filename %>"><%= filename %></a></li>
  <%   } %>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```